# How to run a mass update/delete query in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 Linq2Sql classes: `Parent` and `Child`.  I want to do things like removing all children for a parent, or updating all child records.  In SQL I would have written:

```
delete Child where ParentID = @p
```

or

```
update Child set Val = Val+1 where ParentID = @p
```

I can do this in Linq the brute force way inside the `Parent` class:

```
Children.ToList().ForEach(c => c.DeleteOnSubmit()); // DeleteOnSubmit is my own method
```

and

```
Children.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Val++);
```

But given Linq's inherent performance penalty on ForEach loops, this seems like a very inefficient way to do things.  Is there some way of achieving the desired end that will fire off exactly one query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this link : It's using ExpressionTree : 
http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx
*[Broken Link]*

http://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/
*[Probably the correct one]*

Comment: +1 Wow, this is a great link!  I'm on the verge of changing my mind about answer credit...

Comment: @Shaul This might be a great answer now, but link only answers have this problem that sooner or later they become worthless, because the external resource can no longer be reached. It's always better to write at least a part of the solution here so it will be available as long as SO lives.

Comment: @MarcinHabuszewski - acknowledged, thank you.  5 years later, I never use Linq2Sql anymore, and Entity Framework Extended has native support for this.

Answer (score 14):

For these cases you can use the [DataContext.ExecuteCommand method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) to directly execute SQL on your database. For example:

```
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("delete Child where ParentID = {0}", parentId);
```

Comment: Ugh, that's ugly. Doesn't using literal SQL defeat half the purpose of using Linq?

Comment: @Shaul, For the most part, yes, but LINQ-To-SQL doesn't support mass update/delete, so that's your option.  Another option would be a stored procedure.

Comment: Sometimes we *need* to use ugly code. You can unuglify it a little by confining it inside a method, `DeleteChilds(parentId)`or the like.

Comment: Sorry about withdrawing the answer credit - but take a look at Terry Aney's solution to this problem, and I think you'll agree this is a freakin' brilliant (and elegant) approach!

Comment: This approach is standard SQL and handles the task efficiently and quickly with an EXTREMELY efficient, fast, simple query. Having to use an "ExpressionTree" or loops or anything like that seems completely absurd to me. Linq is a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to http://magiq.codeplex.com mass operation with linq.

Answer (score 1):

**Update and Delete**

A current limitation of the Entity Framework is that in order to update or delete an entity you have to first retrieve it into memory. Also, for single deletes, the object must be retrieved before it can be deleted requiring two calls to the database. To overcome this problem we have to extend the current entity framework using EntityFramework.Extended. EntityFramework.Extended have useful features like Batch Update and Delete, Audit log, Query Result cache, Future Queries. Batch update and delete eliminates the need to retrieve and load an entity before modifying it. Here are a few lines of code to demonstrate how to delete, update.

Install via nuget

**PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.Extended**

**Update**

Scenario: Update customers which have country USA. 
If we do this without any extensions, we have to fetch all customers which have country USA, modify the list and update it using loops. Using Entity Framework.Exdended we don’t need to fetch the list of customers, simply add where condition, set update data and execute query.

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{   
    using(var db = new DataContext())   
    {   
        db.Customers.Where(c => c.Country == "USA").Update(c => new Customer()   
        {   
            Country = "IN"   
        });   

        foreach(var customer in db.Customers.ToList())    
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("CustomerInfo - {0}-{1}-{2}", customer.Name, customer.Country, customer.Status);   
        }   
    }   

    Console.ReadLine();   
}
```

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/entity-framework-batch-994cd739

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
_db.tblStockAllocationEurails.Where(t => t.StockNo >= From && t.StockNo <= To).ToList().ForEach(t => t.StatusID = NewGuid);
_db.SaveChanges();
```