# How to insert/update/delete multiple objects with a single query in Linq to Sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Linq to Sql handles every insert/delete/update operation on an object with separate query. Is there a way to unite multiple operations in single query?

I know this is not possible with the default behavior of the framework. I'm looking for an extension method or workaround. I want to use the queries generated by Linq to Sql, not my own queries or stored procedures but unite multiple operations in a single round-trip to the database.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's a single query, or if it is multiple queries which are sent together through one connection?

Comment: Out-of-the-box: No. With extensions, yes. I have written a couple of datacontext extensions that will do that. Used to have it in a couple of articles in my old blog, but that one is offline for the moment. Will try to repost in my new blog sometime soon...

Comment: I want to submit all changes in a single query for performance reasons only. The fastest way I know is using SqlCommand with Bulk Insert and Bulk Delete but I want to use the linq programming model and leave the query generation to Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this post : [How to run a mass update/delete query in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952677/how-to-run-a-mass-update-delete-query-in-linq/1953244#1953244)

It's a link to how to implement a batch update, batch delete ... hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL does not give you a way to specify a set-based update/delete against the database. The only alternative that I am aware of is to use use SQL directly, which you can do using the database context object.

Randy

Comment: I don't want to write the query. I want to keep the linq to SQL generated one. I need a workaround to execute multiple operations in a single query.