# C# code to bulk update SQL server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, generics

We have this C# code that will update SQL server database table based on flags in a structure.

```
public struct stSRK
{ 
    public string Sno;
    public string SClaimID;
    public bool SType;
    public string SText; 
}
```

Data in the structure can go upto 5000-10000 records at a time.Currently we are using the following C# code to update the database and it makes 'n' number of database calls based on the struct. Would help there is an alternative to do a bulk update using the same struct . Please see the method below

```
public int UpdateClaims(List<stSRK> _lt, string strClaimType)
{
try
{
    int iCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _lt.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_lt[i].sType == true)
            {
                if (_lt[i].SText == 'A')
                {
                iCount += Convert.ToInt16(SQL.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE table SET ClaimType = '" + strClaimType + "' WHERE 
                    (Sno = '" + _lt[i].Sno + "' AND ClaimID = '" + _lt[i].SClaimID + "')"));
                }
                else
                {
                iCount += Convert.ToInt16(SQL.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE table SET ClaimType = '" + strClaimType + "' WHERE 
                    (Sno = '" + _lt[i].Sno + "' AND ClaimID = '" + _lt[i].SClaimID + "')"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_lt[i].SText == 'B')
                {
                iCount += Convert.ToInt16(SQL.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE table SET ClaimType = '" + strClaimType + "' WHERE 
                    (Sno = '" + _lt[i].Sno + "' AND ClaimID = '" + _lt[i].SClaimID + "')"));
                }
                else
                {
                iCount += Convert.ToInt16(SQL.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE table SET ClaimType = '" + strClaimType + "' WHERE 
                    (Sno = '" + _lt[i].Sno + "' AND ClaimID = '" + _lt[i].SClaimID + "')"));
                }
            }
        return iCount;
        }
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to be the same for all cases..

Can't you rewrite your code to build just one SQL statement?

Something like this:

```
public int UpdateClaims(List<stSRK> _lt, string strClaimType)
{
    try
    {
        string allSno = String.Join(",", _lt.Select(l=> l.Sno.ToString()).ToArray());
        string allClaimID = String.Join(",", _lt.Select(l=> l.SClaimID.ToString()).ToArray());

        // Warning: NOT Production code, SQLInjection hazard!
        return Convert.ToInt16(SQL.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE table SET ClaimType = '" + strClaimType + @"' WHERE 
                        (Sno IN(" + allSno + ") AND ClaimID IN(" + allClaimID + "))"));
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //This is not a good idea, as this way you loose all innerException 
        // information about the exception. And you might just want to remove 
        // the try-catch alltogether if you just rethrow the exception.
        throw e.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting: this approach does not scale very well to larger updates - ideally should be a hybrid approach where you do batches of 1,000 records (or whatever makes sense for the types of records/environment you are dealing with). If you try the above with 200,000 records, SQL server will likely choke horribly on the query parsing.

Comment: Also, there may be a logical flaw in your proposed where clause: If I want to delete a record where `Sno=1 AND ClaimID=2`, and I want to delete another record where `Sno=2 AND ClaimID=1`, I will also accidentally be deleting records where `Sno=1 AND ClaimID=1` or `Sno=2 AND ClaimID=2`.

Comment: Thanks Tao, you are very right and I should've mentioned this in my answer. I jumped to the probably wrong assumption that they are always unique. It is up to the OP to put this into context as I have no clue what Sno means.

Comment: That has SQL injection written all over it.  While it is just a refactoring of the OP's code, I would really suggest that your own answer parameterize the query.  Answers have a way of being used by others as gospel.

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```
 DataTable tblDetails = new DataTable("tblPlanDetail");

        tblDetails.Columns.Add("row1").DataType = typeof(Int32);
        tblDetails.Columns.Add("row2").DataType = typeof(DateTime);
        tblDetails.Columns.Add("row3").DataType = typeof(String); ;
        tblDetails.Columns.Add("row4").DataType = typeof(Int32); ;


        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(monthYear.Year, monthYear.Month); j++)
            {
                DataRow row = tblDetails.NewRow();

                DateTime DayOfMonth = new DateTime(monthYear.Year, monthYear.Month, j);
                row["row1"] = idPlan;
                row["row2"] = DayOfMonth;
                row["row3"] = table.Rows[i][0];
                row["row4"] = Int32.Parse((string)table.Rows[i][j]);

                tblDetails.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        try
        {

            SqlBulkCopy sqlbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("row1", "row1");
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("row2", "row2");
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("row3", "row3");
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("row4", "row4");

            sqlbulk.DestinationTableName = "tblPlanDescription";
            sqlbulk.BatchSize = 2;
            sqlbulk.WriteToServer(tblDetails);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

That is bulk insert. 
You can insert it into temp table.
Then you can execute SP, which will create neccessary indexes and update neccesary data on server side

look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889123/any-way-to-sqlbulkcopy-insert-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use linq queries for mass update. That will improve performance of the application.

You can get help for mass updation linq queries over here:

[How to run a mass update/delete query in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952677/how-to-run-a-mass-update-delete-query-in-linq)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339.aspx

Hope this will help you.

Comment: NO!  Linq is slower (sometimes extremely slower) than ADO.Net for bulk operations.

Comment: @EricJ. is it? i thought linq is faster. I also use Linq for 25000 to 30000 records insertion,updation deletions. i observed, it makes operation faster for 20 records per seconds than ADO.NET

Comment: @Freelancer Yes, **Bulk Operations** on SQL data can be much, much faster than the equivalent Linq.  Linq inserts/updates are done record by record, where a bulk operation can insert/update thousands of records in a single operation.

Comment: @Freelancer: Do you mean Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities (EF)?  I have not used Linq-to-SQL, but Linq-to-Entities is *way* slower in my use case.  Google *entity framework slow* and you will see many posts on the issue.

Comment: @EricJ.: EF is slower in pretty much *all* cases

Comment: @EdS.: There's certainly overhead associated with the EF abstraction layers.  Then again, *some* programmers write some pretty bad DB access code.  I would bet that there are *some* cases were *some* programmers will benefit from EF in terms of performance.  In many common cases EF will be slower than what a good programmer would write, but trivially so.  Then there are cases like mass update where EF's performance issues compared to hand-written code really matter.

Comment: @EricJ.: Yeah, I'm just bitter.  I'm a systems guy, so not a lot of DB experience, and I've had to pull EF out of two programs due to performance issues. It's my own fault really; I used it for something it was never intended for.  I do question some design choices (namely it's "chatty" nature and massive memory consumption), but now I only use it for trivial db access patterns, where it works great.